Unpivoting a dataframe by splitting column names
I have the following dataframe:



volume_brand1
volume_productX_brand1
amount_brand1
amount_productX_brand1
volume_productX_brand2
amount_productX_brand2




1000
100
10
50
2000
200



etc...
I would like to unpivot this dataframe to look the following:



brand
product
volume
amount




brand1
productX
100
50


brand1
"not product X"
1000
10


brand2
productX
2000
200



etc..
I've tried using pandas' melt function but have not been successful. As every column has to be unpivoted there is no value for id_vars any help would be appreciated!

Another possible solution:

It renames the columns to create a consistent pattern using str.replace, then stacks the dataframe to convert it from wide to long format.

After stacking, the level_1 column is split into metric, product, and brand, and these columns are concatenated back to the original data.

Finally, the dataframe is pivoted to return it to a wide format, where volume and amount become separate columns, organized by brand and product.


df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(
    r'(volume|amount)_(brand)', r'\1_NotProductX_\2', regex=True)

d = df.stack().reset_index()

(pd.concat([
    d, d['level_1'].str.split('_', expand=True)], axis=1).iloc[:, [5, 4, 3, 2]]
 .set_axis(['brand', 'product', 'metric', 'value'], axis=1)
 .pivot(index=['brand', 'product'], columns='metric', values='value')
 .reset_index())

Output:
metric   brand      product  amount  volume
0       brand1  NotProductX      10    1000
1       brand1     productX      50     100
2       brand2     productX     200    2000


you can use stack and pivot_table,
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'volume_brand1': [1000],
    'volume_productX_brand1': [100],
    'amount_brand1': [10],
    'amount_productX_brand1': [50],
    'volume_productX_brand2': [2000],
    'amount_productX_brand2': [200]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_stacked = df.stack()

df_stacked = df_stacked.reset_index()
df_stacked.columns = ['row', 'original_column', 'value']

df_stacked[['metric', 'product', 'brand']] = df_stacked['original_column'].str.extract(r'(volume|amount)_([^_]+)(?:_(.*))?')

df_stacked = df_stacked.drop(columns=['original_column', 'row'])

df_pivoted = df_stacked.pivot_table(index=['brand', 'product'], columns='metric', values='value').reset_index()

df_pivoted['brand'] = df_pivoted['brand'].ffill()
df_pivoted['product'] = df_pivoted['product'].fillna('not product X')

df_pivoted['volume'] = df_pivoted['volume'].astype(int)
df_pivoted['amount'] = df_pivoted['amount'].astype(int)

df_pivoted.columns.name = None
df_final = df_pivoted[['brand', 'product', 'volume', 'amount']]

print(df_final)


Output,
    brand   product  volume  amount
0  brand1  productX   100    50
1  brand2  productX  2000   200


You can use melt and pivot_table to do the transformation:
# Assuming `df` is your original DataFrame

df_melted = df.melt()

df_melted['brand'] = df_melted['variable'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[-1])
df_melted['product'] = df_melted['variable'].apply(
    x: 'productX' if 'productX' in x else 'not product X'
)
df_melted['metric'] = df_melted['variable'].apply(
    lambda x: 'volume' if 'volume' in x else 'amount'
)

df_unpivoted = df_melted.pivot_table(
    index=['brand', 'product'], columns='metric', values='value', aggfunc='first'
).reset_index()
df_unpivoted = df_unpivoted.sort_values("volume").reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_unpivoted)

Result:
metric   brand        product  amount  volume
0       brand1       productX      50     100
1       brand1  not product X      10    1000
2       brand2       productX     200    2000

